# Malloc adding one to initializing a char for string concat C

Tags: c, malloc, concatenation

I found this function on stackoverflow which concates two strings together. Here is the function:

```
char* concatstring(char *s1,char *s2)
{
 char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);
 strcpy(result,s1);
 strcat(result,s2);
 return result;
}
```

My question is, why do we add 1 to the malloc call?

Answer (score 3):

It's because in C "strings" are stored as arrays of chars followed by a null byte. This is by convention. Consequently, null bytes may not appear inside any C string.

However, the actual string itself does not contain the null byte (which is just part of the *representation* of the string), and so `strlen` reports the number of *non-null* bytes in the string. To create a C string that is the result of concatenating two strings, you thus need to leave room for the null terminator.

In fact, *every* string operation one way or another needs to deal with the null terminator. Unfortunately, the details vary from function to function (e.g. `snprintf` does it right, but `strncpy` is dangerously different), and you should read each function's manual very carefully to understand who takes care of the null terminator and how.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate space for the '\0' (NULL character) which is used to terminate strings in C.

i.e. the string "cat" is actually "cat\0".

Comment: Rather, "`"cat"` is actually `{ 'c', 'a', 't', 0 }`."

Answer (score 0):

If the string is "cat":

```
char * mystring = "cat";
```

Then strlen(mystring), would return 3.

But in reality it takes 4 bytes to store mystring, with one byte to store null character.

So if you have two strings, "dog" and "cat", their length will be 3 and 3 , although the number of bytes required to store them would be 4 each. The memory required to store their concatenation would be 3+3 +1 = 7.

So the 1 in malloc is to allocate extra byte to store the null character.