# Problem: Calling a method in main() which belongs to a class in another .h and .cpp file does not work

Tags: c++

I have a problem that I have not been able to solve. I have a class called "paquetes" which is split into .h and .cpp files. The class stores the method "char * GenerarID()" which generates an ID code. This code is 7 characters, the first two random numbers, the third a random letter, and the last 4 is a sequence starting from 0000 and adding 1. The function is prepared to return an array of characters of the ID code. However, when creating an object in main() of the "paquetes" class, when I compile and execute, I don't get the ID code in the console. ¿What is the error?

Here the code:

.h "Paquetes" (omit structures).

```
#ifndef PAQUETES_H
#define PAQUETES_H
#define N1 100

struct CoordenadasGPS {
    char latitud[10];
    char longitud[10];
};

struct Etiqueta{
    char codigoID[7];
    struct CoordenadasGPS coordenadas;
    char DNI[9];
};

struct Paquete{
   struct Etiqueta informacion;
   Paquete *siguiente;
};

class Paquetes{
    public:
        Paquetes();
        virtual ~Paquetes();
        int counter;
        char * GenerarID();
        

    protected:

    private:

};

#endif // PAQUETES_H


    ID[2] = letter[rand() % 26];
    ID[3] = numbers[num1];
    ID[4] = numbers[num2];
    ID[5] = numbers[num3];
    ID[6] = numbers[num4];

    char *str = (char*)malloc(7 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(str,ID);



    return str;
}
```

.C

.cpp "Paquetes".

```
#include "Paquetes.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"
#include <locale.h>
#include <random>
#include <malloc.h>
#include "malloc.h"
#include "string.h"

using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;

int counter = 0;

Paquetes::Paquetes(){

}

Paquetes::~Paquetes(){
    //dtor
}
char* Paquetes::GenerarID(){
    char ID[7];
    char letter[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char numbers[] = "0123456789";
    int num1, num2, num3, num4;
    int contaux;
    num1 = 0;
    num2 = 0;
    num3 = 0;
    num4 = 0;
    contaux = counter;
    cont++;

    num1 = contaux / 1000;
    contaux -= num1 * 1000;
    num2 = contaux / 100;
    contaux -= num2 * 100;
    num3 = contaux / 10;
    contaux -= num3 * 10;
    num4 = contaux;

    ID[0] = numbers[rand() % 10];
    ID[1] = numbers[rand() % 10];
    ID[2] = letter[rand() % 26];
    ID[3] = numbers[num1];
    ID[4] = numbers[num2];
    ID[5] = numbers[num3];
    ID[6] = numbers[num4];

    char *str = (char*)malloc(7 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(str,ID);



    return str;
}
```

Main() file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"
#include <locale.h>
#include "Paquetes.h"
#include "mem.h"
#include "string.h"

using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;
//int cont =0;




int main(){
    

        Paquetes p;
        char *codeID = p.GenerarID();
        free(codeID);
        cout<<codigo;



return 0;

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Malloc adding one to initializing a char for string concat C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546654/malloc-adding-one-to-initializing-a-char-for-string-concat-c)

Comment: Also, a better design would be to have `counter` as a static member variable of `Paquetes`.